# Запрос становится не читабельный после второго "AND"?

Tags: sql

```
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AVG(Отметки.Отметка) DESC) ID,
           [Список студентов].ФИО,
           [Список студентов].Группа,
           Отметки.[Номер зачётки],
           Отметки.Полугодие,
           AVG(Отметки.Отметка) AS [Средний балл]
    FROM [Список студентов],
         Отметки
    WHERE [Список студентов].[Номер зачётки] = Отметки.[Номер зачётки]
          AND Отметки.Полугодие IN(1, 2)
    AND [Список студентов].Группа IN('41СПО')
    GROUP BY [Список студентов].ФИО,
             [Список студентов].Группа,
             Отметки.[Номер зачётки],
             Отметки.Полугодие
)
ORDER BY [Средний балл] DESC;
```

Выше сам запрос, после ключ. слово WHERE, список условий, которые нужно отобразить, и вот если в запросе два AND после WHERE, как указано, то запрос просто не работает, если одно AND удалить, то запрос срабатывает, подскажите в чём причина. А ещё, если OR поставить вместо AND, то работает , но OR не нужен, нужно именно AND!

Comment: что значит *запрос не работает*? возвращает пустой набор или падает с ошибкой?

Comment: какая субд? sql server?

Comment: Военкомат интересуется как составить запрос на получение данных о студентах. Хммм.

Comment: @Hivemaster замечательное наблюдение ))

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что "просто не работает", это работает, но ничего не возвращает. А это может означать только одно: в исходных данных нет ни одной записи для группы 41СП0 ни в первом ни во втором полугодиях

Comment: @Mike там ещё и подозрительные скобочки, наводящие на мысль, что это подзапрос...

Comment: Anatol, SQL SERVER 2017 , VISUAL STUDIO 2017.

Comment: @Mike, ничего не возвращает, но группа такая есть! Напишите верный запрос, как считаете правильным, срочно нужно

Comment: @Anatol, я весь код запроса кинул, помогите , срочно, работает в sql server management, но не в visual studio 2017